# HTML input form border not styling correctly

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to get a solid black border around my form text input, but the border will not style correctly. Here is my code:

```css
#forminput {
  border: solid black !important;
  border-top: solid black !important;
  border-bottom: solid black !important;
  border-width: 0 2px !important;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
button {
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 30px !important;
  background-color: #095ba0 !important;
  border: 1px !important;
  border-color: #095ba0 !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  cursor: pointer !important;
  border-radius: 2px !important;
}
```

```html
<form action="*" method="POST">
  <input id="forminput" type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username" ><br><br>
  <input id="forminput" type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password" ><br><br>
  <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
</form>
```

But my form input look like below. What am I doing wrong?
[image: this].

Comment: Please don't abuse `!important`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the top and bottom border widths to `0`.

Don't do that.

```css
#forminput {
  border: solid black!important;
  border-top: solid black!important;
  border-bottom: solid black!important;
  border-width: 2px!important;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<input id="forminput">
```

and you can remove all the redundant stuff while you're at it

```css
#forminput {
  border: solid black 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<input id="forminput">
```

Comment: @isaa6 If you find an answer that best solves your question, feel free to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#forminput {
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

This will place a 2px solid black border on the top, right, bottom and left of your input.